# Hot Fuzz names of those arrested by Officer Angel

Tags: hot-fuzz, cornetto-trilogy

Is there any link or joke connecting the names of all the people arrested by Simon Pegg's character in Hot Fuzz, especially the order they are arrested in?

Comment: In which scene (i.e. his first night in Sandford, the NWA) or the entire film?

Comment: The whole film. Between the mugshots and filling in of paperwork there is a lot of names given screen time. Given the amount of waster eggs and in-jokes I just thought there may be something to it that I've missed.

Comment: Perhaps you could *list* the names so we can make any associations?

Comment: If I had the list I would be able to do that myself. Should have made that clear. Don't have time at the moment. Maybe should close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see any overall recipe for the order that any the arrestees arrived in custody and only a few vague puns connecting some of the residents names to their professions and roles i.e.:

The Porters - landlord and landlady of Pub, Dr Robin Hatcher - Delivered Danny among what I would assume were many babies born in Sandford, Rev. Shooter - Comes out blasting during the shoot out in the square, 'Lurch' Armstrong - kind of speaks for itself...

There are a couple more like that (a green fingered Leslie 'Tiller') but despite having seen the film countless times and having listed to the many comments made by Edgar Wright & Co., there does not seem to be any hidden joke or meaning within this, say as opposed to *Shaun of the Dead*, during which Ed prefigures the events of the upcoming apocalypse (the 'plan' for the day which starts with a 'Bloody Mary' and ends in them returning to Winchester for 'shots'.)

Comment: Actually, there is a prefiguring of events.  Danny asked Nicholas a load of questions (Have you ever fired your gun in a high speed pursuit?  Have you ever fired two guns while jumping through the air? Have you ever fired your gun in the air and gone aaahhhhh? etc.) and with the exception of the gun in the air one (which Danny does), Nicholas does them all at the film's climax.

Comment: Thanks guys! The amount of detail put into the Cornetto trilogy films is superb. I suppose everyone know Simon Peg and Edgar Wright play zombies in Dawn of the Dead?

Comment: @Seamousthedog Yeah.  I've got Simon's autobiography and there's a photo of him and Nick in full make up in it.